# Smooth manifold's definition and initial topology

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold. Then it has a topology on it (I'm using Lee's notion of smooth manifold). Well, suppose that $\phi_\alpha: U_\alpha \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a coordinate chart in the maximal atlas. Take on $M$ the coarsest topology making any $\phi_\alpha$ continuous. Is such a topology (i.e. the initial topology induced by $\phi_\alpha$) the same as the topology induced by the smooth structure?

Comment: This is not what initial topology is

Comment: The smoothness is a red herring. The question is about the underlying topological manifold structure.

Comment: @TedShifrin then, what to sat about my question? I think that they agree but I'm not able to show it.

Comment: Yes, so surely the initial topology is contained in the topology induced by the smooth atlas. Does the converse also hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $M$ is a $0$-dimensional smooth manifold with maximal atlas $\{\varphi_\alpha\}$ and $\mu = \tau(\{\varphi_\alpha^{-1}(V) : V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^0\text{ is open}\})$ is the standard topology on $M$ (here $\tau(\mathcal{A})$ denotes topology generated by $\mathcal{A}$), so that $\mu$ is the discrete topology, and consider indiscrete topology $\tau = \{\emptyset, M\}$ on $M$. Then $U_\alpha = \{x_\alpha\}$ are one-point sets, and so $\varphi_\alpha:(U_\alpha, \tau\restriction_{U_\alpha}) = \{x_\alpha\}\to \mathbb{R}^0$ are trivially continuous, but unless $|M|\leq 1$, the indiscrete topology does not agree with the discrete topology on $M$. This shows that the smallest topology on $M$ which makes the charts $\varphi_\alpha$ continuous, which is $\tau$, does not coincide with $\mu$.

Its interesting to ask what happens when $n \geq 1$.

---

Note however that if $\tau$ is the smallest topology for which $\varphi_\alpha$ are continuous **and** $U_\alpha$ are open, then $\tau \subseteq \mu$, but also since given open $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, the set $\varphi_\alpha^{-1}(V)\subseteq U_\alpha$ is open in $(U_\alpha, \tau\restriction_{U_\alpha})$ and $U_\alpha$ is open in $(M, \tau)$, it follows that $\varphi_\alpha(V)^{-1}\in \tau$. Since sets of the form $\varphi_\alpha^{-1}(V)$ generate the topology $\mu$, we have $\mu\subseteq \tau$, so $\mu = \tau$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez This has all to do with the question, the question is about if the topology induced by the charts $\varphi_\alpha$ as a manifold, that is $\{\varphi_\alpha^{-1}(V) : V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\text{ open}\}$ and the smallest topology such that the charts $\varphi_\alpha$ are merely continuous with $U_\alpha$ having subspace topology, coincide.

Comment: Something a student encountering a definition of topology given to a smooth manifold might question

Comment: The topology is not "random", mind you, its the smallest topology which makes all $\varphi_\alpha$ continuous. A smooth manifold does not have topology a priori, it has smooth charts. According to Lee definition.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez There is no such thing as initial topology per what author is suggesting. Thats not what initial topology is. So the only rational thing is to interpret the question how I did it (which is included in the question as well)